# How to detects nodejs modules with c#

Tags: c#, node.js

I trying to detect svgo. But i can't get any result. Just coming empty. You think, where am i doing wrong or is there any way for that? Thanks in advance.

```
        var proc1 = new Process
        {
            StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = "npm.cmd",
                Arguments = "/c npm ls",
                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                CreateNoWindow = true
            }
        };

        proc1.Start();
        string line = "";

        while (!proc1.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
        {
            line += proc1.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
        }


        if (line.Equals("svgo"))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: Have you checked what the output of the command is? If you set a breakpoint on the `if (line.Equals("svgo"))` line and inspect the value of `line` it should give you an idea of what the issue is.

Comment: I checked on c# and i can't get any. But It works and coming a json object when I manually write on the command line window.

Comment: Do you have a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found the solution. Actually my codes are correct but not enough. Svgo and Svg-join plugins have to be installed as global. To see the end result i have to add "-g" code.

The code should be like this:
npm ls -g

For install as global we have to write like this:
npm install svgo -g